# Raspberry Pi A+ does not boot

Tags: boot, board-leds, activity-led, pi-a+

I have a Raspberry Pi A+ that does not boot. When I supply power both the ACT and PWR leds light up and stay on (no blinking). I get no image on the screen whatsoever.

I tried:

- Formatting and rewriting the SD card (using the Raspberry Pi Imager)
- Using a different SD card
- Using a different power supply (2A/5V instead of 1A/5V)
- Powering on without keyboard/mouse/monitor

Nothing worked.
(The SD cards did work on another Raspberry Pi A+)

I tried everything I could find.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or is the Pi dead?

Comment: I assume its a 3A+ so can you boot from USB?  Any bent pins on the SD reader?  What did you do to it before it was dead?

Comment: @Andyroo Why do you assume it's a 3A+? A+ is an existing (older) model.

Comment: @Dirk - fair point.

Comment: @Andyroo It is an older A+ (not 3A+). The SD reader looks fine to me. It has been quite a while since it last worked, but I was using the [CamJam Edukit 3](https://camjam.me/?page_id=1035).

Comment: Please follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) and tell us, what step fails.

Comment: I do not currently own a USB-A to USB-A cable. When I have one, I will try connecting the Pi to my PC to determine if it's dead or not and I will post the result here. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Ingo I tried connecting the Pi to my PC with the USB-A to USB-A cable. The Pi did not show up on my computer as new hardware, so the Pi must be dead.